# How is "Show alerts from my contacts" for Messages in iOS Notification Center supposed to work?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications

I've started using 2-factor authentication with a bunch of services. So, after I sign in, I get an authorisation code SMS'd to me. Now, if my phone is locked, I really don't want code appearing on the lock screen, but I generally like showing the SMS preview.

I noticed in Notification Center -> Messages, there is a choice:

Show Alerts from Everyone
Show Alerts from My Contacts

Now, I assumed that if I chose, "Show Alerts from My Contacts", but kept "Preview" on, if the SMS sender wasn't in my address book, I wouldn't see the Alert, and certainly not the Preview on my lock screen. However, I can't find any discernible difference between these two settings.

Every SMS I get from numbers NOT in my address book, I see the banner if the phone is unlocked, and I see the Preview if it is locked, and I see the Preview on the Lock Screen in the Notifications pulldown.

What gives? Am I misunderstanding the functionality of this setting?

It's an iPhone 5S, running 7.1 (11D167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 different things here which are not pretty clear.

First of all, there's **SMS** and **iMessage**.

And like explained on this [blog](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/restrict-imessage-alerts-to-your-contacts-only/) you can restrict iMessages from giving a notification if you decide you want **contacts only** (since iOS6). This does not work for SMS.

With iOS the name of **Show iMessage alerts from** changed, but the functionality remained the same.